# Integrate AWS API Gateway and Web ACL

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf

Is there a way to associate `web acl` with `aws api gateway` using `python`?
I tried to test my code using `CLI` command

`"*aws waf-regional associate-web-acl --region us-east-1 --web-acl-id '**************' --resource-arn 'arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/******/stages/test'*`

but it is not working, i even tried associating web acl to api gateway from aws console, but the list of web acl's are not listed in the dropdown, though i have already created web acl's.

Comment: Are you sure the web acls are defined in the same region

Comment: We need a more specific explanation of *"it is not working."*  What's the error?

Comment: Yes the issue was with the console, it working perfectly fine in the old AWS console

Comment: We need a more specific explanation of "it is not working." What's the error? -- i was trying to attach web acl to my api gateway, but it was not reflecting on the console whether it is attached or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "waf-regional" (aka WAF Classic API) with WAFv2 parameter.

For WAFv2, you need to call it as:

> aws wafv2 associate-web-acl

Check out documentation for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/associate-web-acl.html

Also, the console not showing the association is a known issueL https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=926212#926212